# Asp.net Boilerplate and Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, aspnetboilerplate

Is [Asp.net Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/)/[Asp.net Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/) has monolithic architecture? i.e. not a microservice architecture. Is that right?

I need to scale up and down the particular component/service server power according to the demand of the users' requests. Like Azure bus service or RabitMQ and etc.

I need to develop a `SaaS` based Resturant web app here. You know that there are periods of the year having a lot of food orders and some time periods having very less. So I need to handle this kind of use cases with server resources i.e. memory/CPU power and etc scaling up and down.

i.e. Can I use Azure Service Bus with Asp.net Zero/Boilerplate? If Yes then can I have little guidance for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Asp.net Boilerplate/Asp.net Zero has monolithic architecture

Asp.net Boilerplate is a generic framework, you can create monolithic or microservice based systems.
AspNet Zero is a monolithic application itself, while you can always create additional services based on the Asp.net Boilerplate framework and communicate with Asp.net zero.

> Can I use Azure Service Bus with Asp.net Zero/Boilerplate? If Yes then can I have little guidance for that?

Yes, you can use. It has no difference from using it with a regular .net project. However, zero/boilerplate source code will not use it, your new code can use. asp.net boilerplate has an EventBus but it is a local event bus and not related to azure service bus.